# Spring JPA - Dropdown list (Filled with data from another table)

Tags: spring, jsp, jpa

I've a problem to insert data to table from my form.

So, I have a two table with relation ManyToOne.

TORDER and TSYSTEM.

I want to insert data to TORDER table via form in my .jsp page. Data for one field is from TSYSTEM table - System Name.

I was able to fill the dropdown list with data from the mentioned table but I have an error message when submitting the form and trying to insert data to TORDER Table.

Do you have any idea why could be wrong here?

My **Order** model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TORDER")
public class Order implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ORDER_ID")
private int orderId;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=System.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "SYSTEM_ID", referencedColumnName = "SYSTEM_ID")
private int sysId;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity=System.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "SYSTEM_NAME", referencedColumnName = "SYSTEM_NAME")
private String systemName;
@Column(name="ORDER_DATE")
private String orderDate;
@Column(name="STATUS")
private String status;
@Column(name="COMMENT")
private String comment;
@Column(name="APPROVED_BY_MANAGER")
private String managerApproval;
@Column(name="APPROVED_BY_ADMIN")
private String adminApproval;

public int getOrderId() {
    return orderId;
}
public void setOrderId(int orderId) {
    this.orderId = orderId;
}

public int getSystemId() {
    return sysId;
}
public void setSystemId(int sysId) {
    this.sysId = sysId;
}

public String getSystemName() {
    return systemName;
}
public void setSystemName(String systemName) {
    this.systemName = systemName;
}

public String getOrderDate() {
    return orderDate;
}
public void setOrderDate(String orderDate) {
    this.orderDate = orderDate;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}
public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getManagerApproval() {
    return managerApproval;
}
public void setManagerApproval(String managerApproval) {
    this.managerApproval = managerApproval;
}

public String getAdminApproval() {
    return adminApproval;
}
public void setAdminApproval(String adminApproval) {
    this.adminApproval = adminApproval;
}

}
```

**System model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TSYSTEM")
public class System implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="SYSTEM_ID")
    private int sysId;  
    @Column(name="SYSTEM_NAME")
    private String systemName; 
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String description; 
    @Column(name="GROUP_NAME")
    private String groupName; 

    public int getSysId() {
        return sysId;
    }
    public void setSysId(int sysId) {
        this.sysId = sysId;
    }
    public String getSystemName() {
        return systemName;
    }
    public void setSystemName(String systemName) {
        this.systemName = systemName;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }
    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

}
```

**Controller** methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addOrder", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addOrder() {
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

Order order = new Order();
model.addObject("orderForm", order);
List<System> systemList = systemService.getAllSystemsName();
model.addObject("systemList", systemList);
model.setViewName("order_form");

return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/saveOrder", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView save(@ModelAttribute("orderForm") Order order) {
 orderService.saveOrUpdate(order);

return new ModelAndView("redirect:/employee/orderList");
}
```

**Repository methods** to get all system names from TSYSTEM Table:

```
public interface SystemRepository extends CrudRepository<System, Integer> {

@Query("select a.systemName from System a")
public List<System> getAllSystemsName();

}
```

and finally my **.jsp form**:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="orderForm" method="post" action="${saveURL }" cssClass="form" >
<form:hidden path="orderId"/>

<table>

    <tr>
            <td>System Name</td>
            <td><form:select path="systemName">
                <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                <form:options items="${systemList}" />
                </form:select>
            </td>
            <td><form:errors path="systemName" cssClass="error" /></td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
    <td><label>Komentarz</label></td>
    <td><form:textarea path="comment" cssClass="form-control" id="comment" 
title="Dodaj komentarz do zamówienia" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><label>Data zamówienia</label></td>
    <td><form:input type="text" path="orderDate" cssClass="form-control" 
id="orderDate" pattern="{2,}" title="Data zamówienia" required="required"/> 
</td>
    </tr>   

    <tr>
    <td><button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Wyczyść dane</button> 
</td>
    <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Zamów dostęp</button> 
</td>
    </tr>   
 </table>
</form:form>
```

and after form submit action i received and error:

```
2018-11-13 17:32:32.846 ERROR 7416 --- [nio-8090-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error accessing field [private int com.project.model.System.sysId] by reflection for persistent property [com.project.model.System#sysId] : 0; nested exception is org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private int com.project.model.System.sysId] by reflection for persistent property [com.project.model.System#sysId] : 0] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set int field com.project.model.System.sysId to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.getInt(UnsafeIntegerFieldAccessorImpl.java:56) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getInt(Field.java:574) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post SYSTEM model. I think you need change System model with field sysId to Integer type. Because you set repository with model sysId is Integer.

Comment: Hello, I've added system model to the questions. Thanks